# Firebase function failing to deploy

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a Firebase Function but I'm running into a deploy error, even when deploying the default `helloworld` function.

The firebase-debug.log file mentions this:
`Could not find image for function projects/picci-e030e/locations/us-central1/functions/helloWorld.`

I have been trying to debug and so far have not been able to solve it...

firebase-debug.log

```
[info] Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    helloWorld(us-central1)
[debug] [2021-11-18T21:54:08.946Z] Missing URI for HTTPS function in printTriggerUrls. This shouldn't happen
[info] i  functions: cleaning up build files... 
[debug] [2021-11-18T21:54:08.948Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/picci-e030e/gcf/us-central1/tags/list [none]
[debug] [2021-11-18T21:54:09.407Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/picci-e030e/gcf/us-central1/tags/list 200
[debug] [2021-11-18T21:54:09.407Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/picci-e030e/gcf/us-central1/tags/list {"child":[],"manifest":{},"name":"picci-e030e/gcf/us-central1","tags":[]}
[debug] [2021-11-18T21:54:09.407Z] Could not find image for function projects/picci-e030e/locations/us-central1/functions/helloWorld
[debug] [2021-11-18T21:54:09.481Z] Error: Failed to create function helloWorld in region us-central1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:38:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Fabricator.createV1Function (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:161:32)
    at async Fabricator.createEndpoint (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:116:13)
    at async handle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:75:17)
[error] 
[error] Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

index.js:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

// Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

// const getBlurhash = require("./get_blurhash");
// exports.getBlurhash = getBlurhash.generateHash;
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
    "blurhash": "^1.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

My version of node:
`v14.16.0`

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Could not find image for function projects/picci-e030e/locations/us-central1/functions/helloWorld.

The Firebase Function deployment failed because it cannot find the image built based on your function app. There might be a problem building in your app, it could be your dependencies or files.

I replicated your issue, received the same error and solved it. There's a problem with the `package.json` file and `package-lock.json`. If you just add(**without installing**) your dependency in `package.json` **you should delete or remove** your `package-lock.json` that will be found in function directory before you deploy it again using the deployment command:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

or you can just **install** your dependency to make sure it will be added to your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` file, deploy again. For example:

```
npm install --save blurhash
```

Comment: Thank you! I was installing the dependencies in the main project folder instead of in the functions folder. I noticed that the package.json didn't include the blurhash dependency and added it manually. Obv that didn't work out. I recreated the project from scratch and installed the dependencies in the functions folder and it deployed successfully.

Comment: running build with --debug showed this as well. `[update-europe-west2-api] Retrying task index 0` I ultimately had to delete the lock file, delete all modules/ and lib/ cachce folders and finally, the project build and deployed.  The red herring was i'd narrowed the build failure down to how long a specific file name was. i.e. A.ts would build. AA.ts would fail.

Comment: Thank you! Deleting package-lock.json and re-deploying did the trick

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that i did not select the right region when calling functions. Set the region on which you have your project on. In my case:

```
export const myfunc = functions.region('europe-west1').https...
```

More info:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations

Answer (score 2):

for others trying to upload cloudfunction with receiving an error.
This may solve your error:

Make sure that the node version you are running is equal to the node version you specified in your package.json file.

search for those two sections in your firebase-debug.log

```
[debug] [2022-02-02T15:57:12.601Z] Node Version:  v16.13.0
```

and

```
[debug] [2022-02-02T15:57:17.055Z] > [functions] package.json contents: {
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
```

and then go to your `firebase/functions/package.json` and change the version for the engines/node property

Answer (score 0):

By removing the `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` folder and then running `npm install` has resolved the issue for me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDPvN.png)